# Node.js: npm doesn't install anymore

Tags: node.js, npm

I don't know what I did wrong, but trying to install a module using npm returns errors. My concrete example (same results, no matter which module I would like to install):

```
npm install socket.io
```

Returns:

```
npm ERR! TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:332:45
npm ERR!     at fs.js:117:20
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:53:5
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:62:5
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:297:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Darwin 11.4.2
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "socket.io"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/Hassen/www/node/btask
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.16
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.69
npm ERR! type non_object_property_call
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Hassen/www/node/btask/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is usually caused by a .git directory in current directory on which no commit has been made.

Either remove the directory or make at least one commit before trying `npm` again.

EDIT: From [this npm issue page](https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/3002);

> This issue has been fixed in the latest release. Please update to the latest node and npm (v0.8.17 and v1.2.0, respectively)

Comment: You're right Joachim! Indeed, I first started to init git before creating any file in the project. Can you advice me about initing a git project?